# Get HTML element's height / width before showing it to a user

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, height

There is an html element created out of DOM and I need to get its height before appending it to its right place in the DOM. I've read a number of topics on stackoverflow. All of them are about switching the element display-visibility and playing with it's position before and after measurement. Like this:

```
myElement.style.position = 'fixed'
myElement.style.left = '-9999px'
// append myElement to visible html node
myElement.getBoundingClientRect()
// and other calculations
// turn back 'position' and 'left' styles
```

In my case I can't just switch visibility via `display` because it leads to flickering due to operations multiplicity and viewport top scroll position adjustements.

So is this the only way as of 2017? How do I make it more efficient,
with highest performance and less possible side effects on the UI?

Comment: I'd probably consider this from another perspective - why do you need view specific data before it's in the view? Is their another way to achieve the same final result without getting the height before loading into the DOM? Maybe elaborating on your specific case might lead to more creative solutions that aren't as technically specific.

Comment: @damanptyltd The height of the injected element is used for scrollbar params adjustment. This height could be random because it depends on external data. In some cases (e.g. multiple appending to the top of the viewport) the process of this adjustment affects the UX by noticeable scrollbar jumping. Do you see quite another way there?

Comment: @dhilt I know it's an old post, but did you find a good way of doing this?

Comment: @mikegross Unfortunately no, `-9999px` and `fixed` is still my choice...